# word2vec Analogy Task Data Set

Tags: data-request, nlp

Word2Vec is famous for demonstrating local linear properties on analogy tasks.

The task and dataset were introduced in [Tomas Mikolov, Wen-tau Yih, and Geoffrey Zweig
, *Linguistic Regularities in Continuous Space Word Representations* (NAATL 2013)](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=189726).

That paper gives a link to where the Syntactic task set can be downloaded from. Unfortunately, it is broken.
Googling for it has not yielded me anything.

The semantic set is derived from SemEval-2012 Task 2, so I am pretty sure I can track that down (haven't tried yet).

I know these both exist, and are generally available.
People are still using them to benchmark variations on word-embeddings.

Comment: The joy of research as PDFs… Maybe it's the same data as in https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/source/default/source ?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I think so. I suspect I am going to have to go ask a colleague who has worked on the data set to verify, or give me their copy.

Comment: Sure, I have posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Syntactic task set can be downloaded from https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/source/default/source

---

FYI [What percentage of links posted in published articles are dead?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/51865/452)